# Explain Behavior of HDBSCAN Clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hdbscan

I have a dataset of 6 elements. I computed the distance matrix using Gower distance, which resulted in the following matrix:

[image]

By just looking at this matrix, I can tell that element #0 is similar to element #4 and #5 the most, so I assumed the output of the HDBSCAN would be to cluster those together, and assume the rest are outliers; however, that wasn't the case.

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=2, min_samples=3, metric='precomputed',cluster_selection_epsilon=0.1, cluster_selection_method = 'eom').fit(distance_matrix)
```

**Clusters Formed:**

*Cluster 0:* {element #0, element #2}

*Cluster 1:* {element #4, element #5}

*Outliers:*  {element #1, element #3}

which is a behavior I don't understand. Also, both parameters `cluster_selection_epsilon` and `cluster_selection_method` don't seem to have an effect on my results at all and I don't understand why.

I tried changing the parameters again to `min_cluster_size=2, min_samples=1`

**Clusters Formed:**

*Cluster 0:* {element #0, element #2,element #4, element #5}

*Cluster 1:* {element #1, element #3}

and any other change in the parameters resulted in all points classified as outliers.

Can someone please help explain this behavior, and explain why `cluster_selection_epsilon` and `cluster_selection_method` don't affect the clusters formed. I thought that by setting `cluster_selection_epsilon` to 0.1, I'd be ensuring that the points inside a cluster would be of distance 0.1 or less apart (so that element #0 and element #2 aren't clustered together for instance)

Below is a visual representation of both clustering trials:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As touched upon in the [help page](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_hdbscan_works.html), the core of hdbscan is 1) calculating the mutual reachability distance and 2) applying the single linkage algorithm. Since you do not have that many data points and your distance metric is pre-computed, you can see your clustering is decided by the single linkage:

```
import numpy as np
import hdbscan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([[0.0, 0.741, 0.344, 1.0, 0.062, 0.084],
 [0.741, 0.0, 0.648, 0.592, 0.678, 0.657],
 [0.344, 0.648, 0.0, 0.648, 0.282, 0.261],
 [1.0, 0.592, 0.655, 0.0, 0.937, 0.916],
 [0.062, 0.678, 0.282, 0.937, 0.0, 0.107],
 [0.084, 0.65, 0.261, 0.916, 0.107, 0.0]])

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=2,min_samples=1,
                            metric='precomputed').fit(x)
clusterer.single_linkage_tree_.plot(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True)
```

[image]

The results will be:

```
clusterer.labels_

[0 1 0 1 0 0]
```

Because the minimum number of clusters has to be 2. So the only way the achieve this is to have element 0,2,4,5 together.

One quick solution is to simply cut the tree and get the cluster you intended:

```
clusterer.single_linkage_tree_.get_clusters(0.15, min_cluster_size=2)

[ 0 -1 -1 -1  0  0]
```

Or you simply use something from sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering since you are not relying on hdbscan to calculate the distance metrics.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, but since you mentioned "you do not have that many data points" - How many data points would I need to have for the HDBSCAN to perform well? Are we talking about hundreds or thousands of data points for 3 variables/dimensions as the above example? You also mentioned that you think Agglomerative clustering would perform better if I have a precomputed distance matrix, why is that?

Comment: see https://pberba.github.io/stats/2020/01/17/hdbscan/ as the name suggest, you need some kind of density estimation to start getting clusters and outliers.. 6 points might not be enough

Comment: in this example you have, my point is to get the clustering you need, you can try using the average or complete algorithm from Agglomerative clustering and you will see it works